# MySQL performance issue on large table - how can I cache results effectively?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design

I have a MySQL table to store user statistics with >2MM rows and 8 columns and an index on the userID. When the user visits his profile a lot of those informations are retrieved from the database resulting in - worst case - a couple of dozen `SELECT` queries sometimes joined with other tables. It is similar to the profile on SO which has to pull a lot of data as well.

Some queries like to get the user score require a `COUNT` and other performance eating MySQL functions. So just the queries for the profile page can take up to 10-20 seconds.

Now my questions:

1. How does a website like SO pull so many informations that quickly?
2. Do I need a caching layer?
3. Should I precalculate the count of
   the score, etc. that consume MySQL performance?
4. Should I use one
   writing optimized table and one reading optimized table? If so how
   could I retrieve live data like on SO?
5. Should I move away from MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > How does a website like SO pull so many informations that quickly?

They give you an illusion of pulling "so much" data, but in reality they get one chunk at a time. Basically, you would need one query to get the COUNT of the results, and another query to get the data for any page within that resultset. The result set is not cached. The parameters to the query may be cached. But it is best to implement in a way the query parameters are supplied with every page request.

> > Do I need a caching layer?

May be. But not necessary to implement this. Caching may be useful to store the previously fetched pages, and the same pages are used by entire community, rather than one user.

> > Should I precalculate the count of the score, etc. that consume MySQL performance?

Not relevant for this use case.

> > Should I use one writing optimized table and one reading optimized table? If so how could I retrieve live data like on SO?

Not required.

> > Should I move away from MySQL?

Not required.

For more details on this concept, lookup paginated Ajax grids

Comment: This is a good answer. Just to summarize, I should reduce the number of queries and instead pull information when needed - so event based. The problem however is that on some pages like the hall of fame, I need a lot of information about a lot of users. So I can't easily reduce the number of queries. So what should be the next step?

Comment: For such intensive queries with a lot of business rules, it is best to compute those views offline periodically and materialize them (temporary tables) and use them as fast access data.
Caching sounds great and actually easy to implement, till get to the issue of invalidating the cache. The more business rules you have behind your data, the harder it is to implement the invalidation. So periodic materialization of the data is easier to implement.

Comment: So you mean I should create temporary tables that just contain e.g. the computet user score since the computing takes most of the time and the `select` on the temporary table would be very fast, right?
There is the disadvantage that the data will not be live though and is only calculated from time to time - which kind of sucks...